# Visual Studio Profile change causes invalid ssl certificate?

Tags: docker, ssl, visual-studio-2019, profile

I have an application that uses Blazor and Docker that can run in multiple modes for multiple customers (loading various configurations and modules). I use the Profile feature in Visual Studio 2019 to change the environment variables, that decide which version of the application to run.

As standard the Docker profile is the active one. When I run the application in this mode, it starts no problem and the development SSL certificate is valid.

I have created some new profiles (and belonging appsettings.*.json files) that I can select here [image]

When I do select one of these profiles they load up fine and the application runs, but for some reason they won't reuse the same development certificate that was working when I am running it in the 'Docker' Profile. How do I fix this?

[image]

I have tried the following:

1. In the secrets.json i have tried to add a line like so: "Kestrel:Certificates:#####Staging:Password": "******" (******) is the same number as the Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password one, that already exists in the file, without any changes to the behavior.
2. From this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide I have tried to create a new certificate by doing this: "dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p crypticpassword" in the terminal (in VS). I switched USERPROFILE to the name of the environment variable, and crypticpassword to a new random guid. It said it already had a valid certificate.

- Do I have to generate a certificate per profile?
- Can I reuse the one that is already working for 'Docker'?
- How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is that this is not supported with docker.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33220#issuecomment-854633300